# Finding possible coefficients to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have this system of linear equations

$$\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+3x_3=2 \\
x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 = 3 \\ 
x_1 + 3x_2 + \alpha x_3 = \beta \\
\end{cases}$$

And I have to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$
that makes the system:

1. Have a single solution
2. Have multiple solutions
3. Have no solutions

I'm trying to use the matrix of the coefficients to calcule the determinant and I'm ending with $\alpha - 5$, meaning that $\alpha$ should be not 5 to  make the system have a single solution, but messing around with a calculator online I found that actually, $\alpha$ needs to be different from 6 to make the system have a single solution, regardless the $\beta$ value.

To make the system have multiple solutions, I also found that $\alpha = 6$ and $\beta = 5$, and to make it have no solutions, $\alpha = 6$ and $\beta \neq 5$.

My question is how to find those values? Because apparently the method I am trying does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single solution is guaranteed when the LHS are linearly independent.

By subtracting the first equation from twice the second, we get

$$x_1+3x_3+5x_3=4,$$ the LHS of which coincides with the third when $\alpha=5$.

Then, if $\beta=4$, the RHS also coincide and the system is compatible.

Comment: So, the values that I got from the online calculator are wrong and the way that I was originally going was right?

Comment: Just confirming that the values from the online calculator were wrong, I used another website to test and I got exactly those values.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your system equation can be writen by
$\begin{cases}
x_1+ x_2 + 3x_3& =2\\
\quad \quad x_2 + x_3& =1\\
\quad  (\alpha - 5) x_3 &= (\beta -4)
\end{cases}$.